# Fitting undirected graphs with fixed missing edges

Tags: regression, machine-learning, graphical-model

**How can we fit a model like the one below, forcing the missing
edges to be omitted?** X can be assumed as Gaussian distribution.

I tried to solve this using the ***modified regression algorithm*** and using ***log-liklihood***. But I am not able to completely conclude it.

The problem what I faced is how to use log-liklihood in this problem. Also the modified regression algorithm is not so clear to me that I can apply in this question.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what your model is, what the "modified regression algorithm" is, and what exactly you're trying to do? Also, do you know a priori which edges are missing?

Comment: Sir, you can find the algorithm here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350055/a-modified-regression-algorithm-for-estimation-of-an-undirected-gaussian-graphic . Actually this is a question related to undirected graphical model. Here we have to find the covariance or inverse of covariance matrix to show relation/dependency between nodes, I think.